# How to make POST request with javascript in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I was wondering if there is anyway to make this:

```
<form action="http[://localhost/.../script.php" method="POST">
```

a regular call. I don't want it to run on form submit, but instead I wan't it to run when I call a function.

Would I use jQuery or AJAX?

Answer (score 4):

You may use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options) on chrome to do so:

```js
// building your form values
var data = new URLSearchParams();
data.set('var1', 'value 1');
data.set('var2', 'value 2');

// send to the endpoint
fetch("http://localhost/.../script.php", {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: data
}).then(function(response) {
    // check the response object for result
    // ...
});
```

Comment: So is variable data an array with two values? Is there anyway to just send over the values separately? Ex. "body: var1, var2"? I already have the value I want to send, just one variable "response".

Comment: The variable `data` here is of the [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) type. You can have as many or as few variables set to it as you want. You can certainly separate the request into many fetch request, too. Just use a different `URLSearchParams` for each fetch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to call the the php function and store its response.

```
$.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
$("#div1").html(result);
  }});
```

Make sure u include jquery CDN

Answer (score 0):

You could use AJAX to post data to your PHP script, which will then run.

Note that jQuery and AJAX are not alternatives for each other.

AJAX is an asynchronous HTTP request (which is what you want).

jQuery is a javascript library which you can use to make AJAX calls.

I would take a look at https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

This is a shorthand function for making an ajax POST request. E.g.:

```
function triggerMyPhpScript(data) {
    $.post("http://localhost/.../script.php", data, function(responseData) {
        // do something with the response of your script
    });
}
```

I also like the Fetch answer from Koala Yeung. This will also work fine on modern browsers. Keep in mind that if you want to support ancient browsers (e.g. internet explorer), you need to implement feature detection and a fallback in case fetch is not supported by the browser.